# SQL How can I avoid ora-38104?

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I want to update big table `TEMP_MA_CONTACT` and I use `MERGE INTO`:

```
MERGE INTO TEMP_MA_CONTACT C
USING (select * from TABLE_TO_CHANGE_2601) T
ON (C.CUSTOMER_RK = T.CUSTOMER_RK)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET C.CUSTOMER_RK = T.NEW_CUSTOMER_RK
```

but Oracle says:

```
ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated
```

Comment: You don't need the `merge` at all.  You are setting a column to a value that it already has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best variant to resolve this problem is:

1) First add rowid to table_to_change_2601

```
    CREATE TABLE table_to_change_2601_new AS 
SELECT T.*,
I.ROWID AS ROW_ID FROM
        table_to_change_2601 T JOIN temp_ma_contact I ON T.CUSTOMER_RK = I.CUSTOMER_RK
```

2) Merge on this rowid's

```
MERGE INTO temp_ma_contact C
USING (select * from table_to_change_2601_new) T
ON (C.ROWID = T.ROW_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET C.CUSTOMER_RK = T.NEW_CUSTOMER_RK
```

Answer (score 1):

Mmmm, I'm not sure if it is possible with merge.. but you can always use update with a subquery:

```
UPDATE TEMP_MA_CONTACT C
set c.customer_rk =
(select P.new_customer_rk from table_to_change_2601 p where P.customer_rk = C.customer_rk)
```

Another idea is this:

```
ALTER TABLE TEMP_MA_CONTACT add TEMP_COL NUMBER(5);
UPDATE TEMP_MA_CONTACT set TEMP_COL = customer_rk;
```

and then use your original merge, but on this column like this:

```
MERGE INTO TEMP_MA_CONTACT C
USING (select * from TABLE_TO_CHANGE_2601) T
ON (C.TEMP_COLUMN = T.CUSTOMER_RK)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET C.CUSTOMER_RK = T.NEW_CUSTOMER_RK;
commit;
```

and then droping the column

```
ALTER TABLE TEMP_MA_CONTACT drop column TEMP_COLUMN
```

Comment: Yes, but it will be very slow

Comment: Would you consider adding a column which is exact copy of the ID column, comparing by it and then droping the column? @Jdzel Edited my answer with my suggestion

Comment: @Jdzel: what makes you think that the UPDATE will be any slower than the MERGE? Both are performing the same work.

Comment: i might add a column only in one table: table_to_change_2601

Comment: @BobJarvis because of subquery

Comment: @sagi i am not sure that i'l be able to alter TEMP_MA_CONTACT

Comment: @BobJarvis well, he is right, usually update with subquery is slower then merge. But did you test it and saw it have poor performance? or you just decide in advance? because you can never know

Comment: @Jdzel First, check if its possible. If its not, you can always make a TEMP table which is a copy of TEMP_MA_CONTACT and do what i said on that, then trunc/insert it into the original table.

Comment: @sagi I dont have enough privileges to alter this table. But I suppose that I found the solution. TEMP_MA_CONTACT has unique id (contact_id), so i joined it with TABLE_TO_CHANGE_2601 and now I can merge this tables on contact_id

Answer (score 0):

[There are a few workarounds that I have described in this blog post here](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/01/02/how-to-work-around-ora-38104-columns-referenced-in-the-on-clause-cannot-be-updated/). One of the workarounds that seems to preserve the performance characteristics of the original query (allowing index usage on `CUSTOMER_RK` columns) is this one, using row value expressions:

```
MERGE INTO TEMP_MA_CONTACT C
USING (select * from TABLE_TO_CHANGE_2601) T
ON ((C.CUSTOMER_RK, 'dummy') = ((T.CUSTOMER_RK, 'dummy')))
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET C.CUSTOMER_RK = T.NEW_CUSTOMER_RK
```

This seems to work up until Oracle 18c